# iOS data structure for app relying on web service

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm building an app that requires internet for browsing content (mostly pictures with text). User can also add the content to their favorites. I have the APIs, and for iOS (Swift + iOS 8. I'm going to use `AFNetworking` for getting the data. However, should I store the results in a Dictionary of Models or in Core Data for an app used in the real world? I have read a lot of tutorials on how to implement each, but I don't know which to use. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Some additional notes, may be helpful in your answer:

1. When user uses app for the first time, app should load and display 20-30 records, but it should do so fast.  Login isn't required.
2. User can scroll to see more content, but content should be fetched fast, may be some even pre-fetched?
3. When user uses app subsequently, and if he/she has logged in previously, app should 
   know who the user is.
4. User can access their favorites on app, but they can also favorite contents on website, so the data needs to be in sync.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a "design my app for me" site.

Comment: I like the question, as its focus is on best practice. There is clearly enough thought in the question, that the OP is not asking for his app to be designed, but a technical question that is rather focused. The question, and the answer so far, were helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using Core Data because its fast, object based and easy to handle but little hard to use. You can have better controls for accessing your data, even when you are loading data part by part you can store and retrieve it later too based on ids and using that you can set like favorites and login or last login status which is a better way then using plist.